# How to register a new user in Firebase Auth database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to migrate from existing Facebook authentication to Firebase authentication.

My current schema:
API server:

- POST /signup?access_token=&id= # Signup endpoint that accepts Facebook ID and access token and responses with: user ID (crated in API server DB) and its tokens pair (access/refresh)
- POST /signin - mostly the same as /signup, but has additional step to check whether the user exesit in the database or not.
- POST /refresh_token?refresh_token= # Returns a new pair of access and refresh tokens

What should I do to seamlessly migrate existing users to Firebase Auth?
I suppose that the first thing I should do is sync new users with Firebase.
So I should add a step to `/signup` handler that will register newly created users in Firebase.

Then I should migrate existing users to Firebase, right? I could success in it with `Firebase CLI` and JSON file with my users, so there is no question with this step.

But I can't understand, how I can do the first step: sync newly users with Firebase.

I use Ruby, that doesn't have Admin SDK implementation, but it is not a  problem for me, REST API is OK.

I think this one https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-sign-in-with-oauth-credential is the right place for start, it looks like definitely what I need.

The problem is in `requestUri` parameter. Documentation says: `requestUri   string  The URI to which the IDP redirects the user back.`. Hm... I don't interact with user at all, it is a server-side code.

What URL should I use? I didn't know and decided to use the default value: `http://localhost`. So it was failed.

UPD 1:

API:

V1:

- /signup => Register user in my DB, issue tokens
- /login
- /refresh_token

V2:

- /signup Deprecated in favor of client side Auth
- /login -//-
- /refresh_token -//-

Client for API v1 (Facebook Auth):

- Authenticate user with Facebook Auth
- Make request to API V1 /signup or /login|/refresh_token

Client for API v2 (Firebase Auth):

- Authenticate user with Firebase/Facebook Auth => Creates user in Firebase DB

What I want is consistent and compatible API for clients V1.
Any existing client (application) for API V1 should be able to send a request to v1/signup endpoint and finish with the same state as clients for V2: user account is created in Firebase

Comment: I find corresponding code in Node.js Admin SDK: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/blob/312c41a258856db899f99557a24fccfa54d5a2af/src/auth/auth-api-request.ts#L814-L857 but can't find actual URL and request parameters (I don't know TS).

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be looking for this resource: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/facebook-login

You'll want to integrate the Facebook Login (and whichever other logins) so users can sign in. If a new user signs in, then Firestore automatically created an account associated with the new user.

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't help me. I probably wasn't clear: I need to have backward-compatibility in API so existing clients (mobile application) should work as before and new users who already install application but haven't registered yet shouldn't receive any errors during sign-up, but the same time I have to sync their account with Firebase. I just find a way to do the same what Firebase CLI `auth:import` does, but on the server, per single user, on its sign-up.

Comment: With Firebase's FB sign in, if the user does not exist in your Firebase Authentication, then upon sign in Firebase will create one for the user. That should take care of any new users and you can import all existing users as you've mentioned.

Comment: Oh, it would be nice, but it is not true. I tried to sign-up through Facebook Auth as a new user, it doesn't create user account in Firebase.

Comment: Thank you for your involvement! I tried to be more clear in my question and updated it (see UPD 1).